# How to use "Pair" in Kotlin dataclass

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `variableA` and `variableB`.
I would like to implement `Arraylist(pair<variableA, variableB>)` in Kotlin data class.
Ofcourse, I can use Arraylist of another class contains variableA and variableB.

```
data class Database(
    val rfHandler: ArrayList<RfHandler> = ArrayList(),
    val btThread: ArrayList<BTThread> = ArrayList(),
)
```

It would be beter if some could suggest other better way if any.

Comment: What's stopping you to use it as `data class SomeClass(val list: ArrayList<Pair< RfHandler, BTThread>>) { } ` ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using Pair data structure?
(One in [AndroidX Pair](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/util/Pair) and other in [Kotlin Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/))

```
val pairlist = ArrayList<Pair<RfHandler, BTThread>>()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct your class as:

`data class Database(val list: ArrayList<Pair<RfHandler, BTThread>>)`

Or if you would like to make your class itself be a pair, then you could extend it like so:

```
data class Database(
    val rfHandler: ArrayList<RfHandler> = ArrayList(),
    val btThread: ArrayList<BTThread> = ArrayList(),
): Pair<ArrayList<RfHandler>, ArrayList<BTThread>>(rfHandler, btThread)
```